# Adding a Custom Button to a UINavigationItem LeftBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem

Could anyone tell me why this code does not working?

```
self.backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow.png"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.backButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[self.backButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(backButtonAction:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.backButton];
[navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backButtonItem animated:NO];
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Edit:

Nothing appears on the `leftBarButtonItem`. That's the problem.

Comment: How is not working? What result are you seeing?

Comment: What's the problem? Is leftButton not displayed or something else?

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? Where do you use that code?

Comment: I guess, problem may be with your image "back_arrow.png". Check what happens if you tap on the area where leftBarButtonItem should display. Does it catch the tap??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> "When creating a custom button—that is a button with the type UIButtonTypeCustom—the frame of the button is set to (0, 0, 0, 0) initially. Before adding the button to your interface, you should update the frame to a more appropriate value."

So you should see something if you set the frame in line 2, eg:

```
self.backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20);
```

Comment: I know it was something silly :) I didn't define a frame for the button. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 0, 30, 30);
self.backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[self.backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow.png"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.backButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[self.backButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(backButtonAction:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: I know it was something silly :) I didn't define a frame for the button. Thanks.